# Directing a user to different scripts from a menu script using inputs?

Tags: python, input

We have to make a program using Python for a college unit and I'm making one that you can use with Twitter. I've done the scripts for posting tweets and viewing them but I want to make it so you can select different options from a sort of menu script and run the scripts from there?

Example:

1. New tweet
2. View tweets
3. Etc

Choose one: 1

Enter tweet:

That sort of thing... Really confused!

Comment: what is the exact problem here??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a text menu like that, use something like this (if using Python 3):

```
while True:  
    print("1. New tweet")
    print("2. View tweets")
    option = input("Choose one: ")
    if option == "1":
        # New tweet
    elif option == "2":
        # View tweets
```